# Which machines support nondeterministic random_device?

Tags: c++, c++11, random, entropy

I need to obtain data from different C++ random number generation algorithms, and for that purpose I created some programs. Some of them use pseudo-random number generators and others use `random_device` (nondeterministic random number generator). The following program belongs to the second group:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <cmath>
#include <random>
using namespace std;

const int N = 5000;
const int M = 1000000;
const int VALS = 2;
const int ESP = M / VALS;

int main() {
    for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
        random_device rd;
        if (rd.entropy() == 0) {
            cout << "No support for nondeterministic RNG." << endl;
            break;
        } else {
            mt19937 gen(rd());
            uniform_int_distribution<int> distrib(0, 1);
            vector<int> hist(VALS, 0);
            for (int j = 0; j < M; ++j) ++hist[distrib(gen)];
            int Y = 0;
            for (int j = 0; j < VALS; ++j) Y += abs(hist[j] - ESP);
            cout << Y << endl;
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see in the code, I check for the entropy to be greater than 0. I do this because:

> Unlike the other standard generators, this [`random_device`] is not meant to be an
>   engine that generates pseudo-random numbers, but a generator based on
>   stochastic processes to generate a sequence of uniformly distributed
>   random numbers. Although, certain library implementations may lack the
>   ability to produce such numbers and employ a random number engine to
>   generate pseudo-random values instead. In this case, entropy returns
>   zero. [Source](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/random/random_device/)

Checking the value of the entropy allows me to abort de data obtaining if the resulting data is going to be pseudo-random (not nondeterministic). Please note that I assume that if `rd.entropy() == 0` is true, then we are in pseudo-random mode.

Unfortunately, all my trials result in a file with no data because of entropy being 0. My question is: what can I do to my computer, or where can I find a machine that allows me to obtain the data?

Comment: What compiler and runtime library are you using? On what operating system? On what hardware?

Comment: You can try a different toolchain. E.g. http://rextester.com/GHJZY51093  instead of http://rextester.com/PVS72980

Comment: @JesperJuhl not relevant to my question really, but I can tell you if you need to know. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @Bob__ Love it. Thanks.

Comment: It's relevant since whether or not `std::random_device` is nondeterministic depends on your hardware, the os running on top, the standard library you use and the compiler you use. So to answer whether you have a nondeterministic `random_device` in your case, it's necessary to have that information. And it's also generally useful information to include in almost *any* question.

Comment: @JesperJuhl Read my question again. I wasn't asking about my computer. But thanks anyway, I liked your comment! My PC is a HP circa 2012, with Ubuntu 16.4 on it. The library is ldd and the compiler g++ 5.0 I think.

Answer (score 3):

The source you cite is misleading you. The [standard](http://eel.is/c++draft/rand.device) says that

> ```
> double entropy() const noexcept;
> ```
>
> Returns: If the implementation employs a random number engine, returns 0.0. Otherwise, returns an entropy estimate for the random numbers returned by operator(), in the range min() to log2(max()+1).

And a [better reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/random_device/entropy) has some empirical observations

> ### Notes
>
> This function is not fully implemented in some standard libraries. For
>   example, LLVM libc++ always returns zero even though the device is
>   non-deterministic. In comparison, Microsoft Visual C++ implementation
>   always returns 32, and boost.random returns 10.

In practice, nearly all the main implementations (targeting general purpose computers) have non-deterministic `std::random_device`s. Your test has a very high false negative rate.

Comment: Thanks Caleth. The reference you brought says "If implementation limitations prevent generating nondeterministic random numbers, the implementation may employ a random number engine". Do you know any of such "implementation limitations"? And if my entropy is always 0, how can I know wether the generated numbers are random or pseudo-random?

Comment: You look in the documentation of your compiler. An example where there isn't nondeterminism would be targeting a microcontroller, those generally don't have a hardware source

Comment: @Manelicus I believe GCC on windows w/ mingw has a deterministic `random_device`.